# Sorting Active Directory Data

Tags: powershell, active-directory

Hello Everyone I would like to sort the names in descending or ascending order, Im trying to put the Sort-Object Attribute in some place but is not working:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=ITE,OU=HQ,DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {

New-Object PSObject -Property @{

UserName = ($_.DisplayName | Sort-Object -Descending)

Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ",  "

}

} | Select UserName, Groups
```

Greetings!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$_.DisplayName` only contains *one* name at a time, so you're effectively not changing anything.

Do the sorting *after* creating your objects:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=ITE,OU=HQ,DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
        UserName = $_.DisplayName
        Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ",  "
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

Comment: Oh yep that worked out haha I put it literally in every place but there. thanks!